# Using GEKKO for Moving Horizon Estimation online 2

Tags: gekko, estimation

This is the following question after appyling comments from: [Using GEKKO for Moving Horizon Estimation online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72678759/using-gekko-for-moving-horizon-estimation-online)

I have studied example from [estimation iterative example on the Dynamic Optimization course website](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/EstimatorTypes) and revised my code as follows:

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

class Observer():

    def __init__(self, window_size, r_init, alpha_init):
        self.m = GEKKO(remote=False)
        self.dt = 0.05
        self.m.time = [i*self.dt for i in range(window_size)]
        #Parameters
        self.m.u = self.m.MV()
        #Variables
        self.m.r = self.m.CV(lb=0) # value=r_init) #ub=20 can be over 20
        self.m.alpha = self.m.CV() # value=alpha_init) #ub lb for angle?
        #Equations
        self.m.Equation(self.m.r.dt()== -self.m.cos(self.m.alpha))
        self.m.Equation(self.m.alpha.dt()== self.m.sin(self.m.alpha)/self.m.r - self.m.u)  # differential equation
        #Options
        self.m.options.MV_STEP_HOR = 2
        self.m.options.IMODE = 5   # dynamic estimation
        self.m.options.EV_TYPE = 2 #Default 1: absolute error form 2: squared error form
        self.m.options.DIAGLEVEL = 0 #diagnostic level
        self.m.options.NODES = 5 #nodes   # collocation nodes default:2
        self.m.options.SOLVER = 3 #solver_num

        # STATUS = 0, optimizer doesn't adjust value
        # STATUS = 1, optimizer can adjust
        self.m.u.STATUS = 0
        self.m.r.STATUS = 1
        self.m.alpha.STATUS = 1
        # FSTATUS = 0, no measurement
        # FSTATUS = 1, measurement used to update model
        self.m.u.FSTATUS = 1 #default
        self.m.r.FSTATUS = 1
        self.m.alpha.FSTATUS = 1

        self.m.r.TR_INIT = 0
        self.m.alpha.TR_INIT = 0

        self.count = 0

    def MHE(self, observed_state, u_data):
        self.count =+ 1
        self.m.u.MEAS = u_data
        self.m.r.MEAS = observed_state[0]
        self.m.alpha.MEAS = observed_state[1]
        self.m.solve(disp=False)
        return self.m.r.MODEL, self.m.alpha.MODEL

if __name__=="__main__":
    FILE_PATH00 = '/home/shane16/Project/model_guard/uav_paper/adversarial/SA_PPO/src/DATA/4end_estimation_results_r.csv'
    FILE_PATH01 = '/home/shane16/Project/model_guard/uav_paper/adversarial/SA_PPO/src/DATA/4end_estimation_results_alpha.csv'
    FILE_PATH02 = '/home/shane16/Project/model_guard/uav_paper/adversarial/SA_PPO/src/DATA/4end_action_buffer_eps0.0_sig0.0.csv'
    cycles = 55
    
    x = np.arange(cycles) # 1...300
    matrix00 = np.loadtxt(FILE_PATH00, delimiter=',')
    matrix01 = np.loadtxt(FILE_PATH01, delimiter=',')
    matrix02 = np.loadtxt(FILE_PATH02, delimiter=',')

    vanilla_action_sigma_0 = matrix02

    vanilla_estimation_matrix_r = np.zeros(cycles)
    vanilla_estimation_matrix_alpha = np.zeros(cycles)

    # sigma = 0.0
    # vanilla model true/observed states
    r_vanilla_sigma_0_true = matrix00[0, 3:] # from step 1
    r_vanilla_sigma_0_observed = matrix00[1, 3:] # from step1
    alpha_vanilla_sigma_0_true = matrix01[0, 3:]
    alpha_vanilla_sigma_0_observed = matrix01[1, 3:]

    # initialize estimator
    sigma = 0.0 #1.0
    solver_num = 3
    nodes = 5
    # for window_size in [5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]:
    window_size = 5
    observer = Observer(window_size, r_vanilla_sigma_0_observed[0], alpha_vanilla_sigma_0_observed[0])
    for i in range(cycles):
        if i % 100 == 0:
            print('cylcle: {}'.format(i))
        vanilla_observed_states = np.hstack((r_vanilla_sigma_0_observed[i], alpha_vanilla_sigma_0_observed[i])) # from current observed state
        r_hat, alpha_hat = observer.MHE(vanilla_observed_states, vanilla_action_sigma_0[i]) # and current action -> estimate current state
        vanilla_estimation_matrix_r[i] = r_hat
        vanilla_estimation_matrix_alpha[i] = alpha_hat

    #plot vanilla
    plt.figure()
    plt.subplot(3,1,1)
    plt.title('Vanilla model_sig{}'.format(sigma))
    plt.plot(x, vanilla_action_sigma_0[:cycles],'b:',label='action (w)')
    plt.legend()
    plt.subplot(3,1,2)
    plt.ylabel('r')
    plt.plot(x, r_vanilla_sigma_0_true[:cycles], 'k-', label='true_r')
    plt.plot(x, r_vanilla_sigma_0_observed[:cycles], 'gx', label='observed_r')
    plt.plot(x, vanilla_estimation_matrix_r, 'r--', label='time window: 10')
    # plt.legend()
    plt.subplot(3,1,3)
    plt.xlabel('time steps')
    plt.ylabel('alpha')
    plt.plot(x, alpha_vanilla_sigma_0_true[:cycles], 'k-', label='true_alpha')
    plt.plot(x, alpha_vanilla_sigma_0_observed[:cycles], 'gx', label='observed_alpha')
    plt.plot(x, vanilla_estimation_matrix_alpha, 'r--', label='time window: {}'.format(window_size))
    plt.legend()
    plt.savefig('plot/revision/4estimated_STATES_vanilla_sig{}_window{}_cycles{}_solver{}_nodes{}.png'.format(sigma, window_size,cycles, solver_num, nodes))
    plt.show()
```

csv files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jW_6zBCdbJHB7yU3HmCIhamEyOT1LJqD?usp=sharing

The code works when initialized with values specified at line 15,16 (m.r, m.alpha).
[image: left estimation result when time window=2, right: time window=50]

**However, if I try with no initial value,(as same condition in [example](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/EstimatorTypes)), solution is not found.**

terminal output:

> cylcle: 0 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "4observer_mhe.py", line 86, in 
> r_hat, alpha_hat = observer.MHE(vanilla_observed_states, vanilla_action_sigma_0[i]) # and current action -> estimate current
> state   File "4observer_mhe.py", line 49, in MHE
> self.m.solve(disp=False)   File "/home/shane16/Project/model_guard/LipSDP/lipenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gekko/gekko.py",
> line 2140, in solve
> raise Exception(apm_error) Exception: @error: Solution Not Found

What could be the solution to this problem?
I have tried below strategies, but couldn't find the solution.

1. Reduce the number of decision variables by using m.FV() or m.MV() with m.options.MV_STEP_HOR=2+ to reduce the degrees of freedom for the solver for the unknown parameters.
2. Try other solvers with m.options.SOLVER=1 or m.options.SOLVER=2.

I expect to see **estimation results that follow the true state well.**
But I guess I'm doing something wrong.
Could anyone help me please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solvers sometimes need good initial guess values or constraints (lower and upper bounds) on the degrees of freedom (`MV` or `FV`) to find the optimal solution.

One of the equations may be the source of the problem:

```py
self.m.alpha.dt() == self.m.sin(self.m.alpha)/self.m.r - self.m.u
```

The initial value of `r` is zero (default) because no initial value is provided when it is declared as `self.m.r = self.m.CV(lb=0)`. A comment suggests that it was formerly initialized with value `r_init`. The zero value creates a divide-by-zero for that equation. Try rearranging the equation into an equivalent form that avoids the potential for divide-by-zero either with the initial guess or when the solver is iterating.

```py
self.m.r*self.m.alpha.dt() == self.m.sin(self.m.alpha) - self.m.r*self.m.u
```

There may be other things that are also causing the model to not converge. When the solution does not converge then the `infeasibilities.txt` file can be a source to troubleshoot the specific equations that are having trouble. Here are instructions to retrieve the `infeasibilities.txt` file: [How to retrieve the 'infeasibilities.txt' from the gekko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56671888/how-to-retrieve-the-infeasibilities-txt-from-the-gekko)